# filter Json array multi key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

I am looking for a solution to let me filter my json with key status = 'p'  exist in lease array.  I tried to use this function it didn't work for me:

```
myActiveContractItems.filter(( myActiveContractItem ) => myActiveContractItem.leases.map( lease => lease.status === LeaseStatus.Primary))
```

The following is my JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445134,
        "reference": "L|2190197",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190197",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -629.64,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-05",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-02-20",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 217.83,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 96.99,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
          "flat_type_id": 618,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 9,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 837057,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 332705,
            "reference": "OP80|SUDE|41|70|AL01|A|2|MISLCAL108",
            "reference_label": "MISLCAL108",
            "label": "MISLCAL108",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1975-12-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|SUDE|41|70|AL01|A|2",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "108",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
            "type_id": 618,
            "real_space": 36,
            "living_space": 31,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334281,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445147,
        "reference": "L|2190211",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190211",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -908.28,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-06",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-02-26",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 331.66,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 122.48,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 2",
          "flat_type_id": 619,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 8,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 837473,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 331154,
            "reference": "OP80|SUDE|52|89|RO02|C|0|PRBLCRO058",
            "reference_label": "PRBLCRO058",
            "label": "PRBLCRO058",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1980-10-16",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|SUDE|52|89|RO02|C|0",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "58",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 2",
            "type_id": 619,
            "real_space": 54,
            "living_space": 54,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334294,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445170,
        "reference": "L|2190237",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190237",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -834.2,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-05",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-03-01",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 311.21,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 105.89,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 4",
          "flat_type_id": 621,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 9,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 826780,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 299105,
            "reference": "OP80|CENT|7|8|AO34|A|4|318LCAO024",
            "reference_label": "318LCAO024",
            "label": "318LCAO024",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1958-11-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|CENT|7|8|AO34|A|4",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "24",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 4",
            "type_id": 621,
            "real_space": 55,
            "living_space": 55,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334319,
          "name": "AXA",
          "insurance_policy": "2659495304",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445240,
        "reference": "L|2190322",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190322",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -4489.57,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-28",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-03-19",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 0,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 0,
          "flat_category": "Foyer",
          "flat_category_id": 283,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
          "flat_type_id": 618,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 1,
          "status": "S",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 840484,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 301118,
            "reference": "OP80|CENT|89|149|DO26|A|1|DODDEDO012",
            "reference_label": "DODDEDO012",
            "label": "DODDEDO012",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1993-08-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80000",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|CENT|89|149|DO26|A|1",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Foyer",
            "category_id": 283,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
            "type_id": 618,
            "real_space": 27,
            "living_space": 27,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [
        {
          "person_id": 904316,
          "person_reference": "2162801",
          "person_first_name": "APREMIS",
          "person_last_name": "APREMIS",
          "birth_date": "1950-01-01",
          "title": "Association",
          "salutation": "ASSO",
          "status": "P",
          "arrival_date": "2019-03-28",
          "departure_date": null,
          "parent_link": null
        }
      ],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334394,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `LeaseStatus` or `LeaseStatus.Primary` in your JSON data, but this works for me:

```js
myActiveContractItems.results.filter(myActiveContractItem => myActiveContractItem.leases.some(lease => lease.status === "P"))
```

If `myActiveContractItems` is already the same as the `results` array, just remove the `.results` from my code above.

This filters the contract items to only contract items that have at least one lease with a status equal to `"P"`.

As a result, one of the four contracts from your data is filtered out, returning the remaining three.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a boolean value for the filter callback function. To detect at least one lease item have status is `P` (instead of `p`, I think so).

Demo:

```js
const input = {
  "results": [
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445134,
        "reference": "L|2190197",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190197",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -629.64,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-05",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-02-20",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 217.83,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 96.99,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
          "flat_type_id": 618,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 9,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 837057,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 332705,
            "reference": "OP80|SUDE|41|70|AL01|A|2|MISLCAL108",
            "reference_label": "MISLCAL108",
            "label": "MISLCAL108",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1975-12-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "1 RUE DES ALPILLES",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|SUDE|41|70|AL01|A|2",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "108",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
            "type_id": 618,
            "real_space": 36,
            "living_space": 31,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334281,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445147,
        "reference": "L|2190211",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190211",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -908.28,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-06",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-02-26",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 331.66,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 122.48,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 2",
          "flat_type_id": 619,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 8,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 837473,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 331154,
            "reference": "OP80|SUDE|52|89|RO02|C|0|PRBLCRO058",
            "reference_label": "PRBLCRO058",
            "label": "PRBLCRO058",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1980-10-16",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "4 ALLEE PIERRE ROLLIN",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|SUDE|52|89|RO02|C|0",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "58",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 2",
            "type_id": 619,
            "real_space": 54,
            "living_space": 54,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334294,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445170,
        "reference": "L|2190237",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80090",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190237",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -834.2,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-05",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-03-01",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 311.21,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 105.89,
          "flat_category": "Logement",
          "flat_category_id": 291,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 4",
          "flat_type_id": 621,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 9,
          "status": "P",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 826780,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 299105,
            "reference": "OP80|CENT|7|8|AO34|A|4|318LCAO024",
            "reference_label": "318LCAO024",
            "label": "318LCAO024",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1958-11-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "34 RUE DU 31 AOUT 1944",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80090",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|CENT|7|8|AO34|A|4",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "24",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Logement",
            "category_id": 291,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 4",
            "type_id": 621,
            "real_space": 55,
            "living_space": 55,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334319,
          "name": "AXA",
          "insurance_policy": "2659495304",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "contract": {
        "id": 445240,
        "reference": "L|2190322",
        "label": "APREMIS",
        "status": null,
        "payment_mode": null,
        "address": {
          "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "billing_address": {
          "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
          "label": null,
          "kind": "main",
          "country": "",
          "federal_state": "",
          "postal_code": "80000",
          "city": "AMIENS"
        },
        "primary_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": "",
          "name_of_account_holder": "",
          "rib": "   ",
          "rum": "",
          "blz": null,
          "account_number": null
        },
        "dedicated_bank_account": {
          "bank": "",
          "iban": "",
          "bic": ""
        },
        "number": "2190322",
        "day_of_collection": 0,
        "direct_debit_start_date": "-0001-11-30",
        "validate": false,
        "balance": -4489.57,
        "signed": true,
        "company": null,
        "contacts": [],
        "rent_components": []
      },
      "leases": [
        {
          "reference": null,
          "metering_service_data": null,
          "start_date": "2019-03-28",
          "end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "presumed_end_date": "-0001-11-30",
          "signing_date": "2019-03-19",
          "expected_rent_deposit": 0,
          "actual_rent_deposit": 0,
          "rent_amount": 0,
          "vat": 0,
          "charge_amount": 0,
          "flat_category": "Foyer",
          "flat_category_id": 283,
          "flat_type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
          "flat_type_id": 618,
          "cost_contribution": 0,
          "tenant_rank": 1,
          "status": "S",
          "end_inspection": null,
          "number_of_occupants": null,
          "move_in_date": null,
          "handover_date": null,
          "move_out_date": null,
          "id": 840484,
          "leaving_reason": null,
          "notice_period": null,
          "flat": {
            "id": 301118,
            "reference": "OP80|CENT|89|149|DO26|A|1|DODDEDO012",
            "reference_label": "DODDEDO012",
            "label": "DODDEDO012",
            "flat_contact": [],
            "valid": {
              "from": "1993-08-01",
              "to": "-0001-11-30"
            },
            "address": {
              "street": "26 -34 RUE DE LA DODANE",
              "label": null,
              "kind": "main",
              "country": "",
              "federal_state": "",
              "postal_code": "80000",
              "city": "AMIENS"
            },
            "unique_credit_identifier": null,
            "parent_reference": "OP80|CENT|89|149|DO26|A|1",
            "legal_model_space": "",
            "useful_space": 0,
            "corrected_space": 0,
            "new_rent_amount": null,
            "rental_charge": null,
            "condition": "",
            "location": "",
            "immovable_property_valuation": 0,
            "valuation_year": 0,
            "comment": null,
            "category": "Foyer",
            "category_id": 283,
            "type": "COLLECTIF TYPE 1BIS",
            "type_id": 618,
            "real_space": 27,
            "living_space": 27,
            "unit_for_flat_space": null,
            "vacant": false,
            "vacant_from": null,
            "vacancy_reason": null,
            "construction_date": "-0001-11-30",
            "floor": null,
            "bk01": {
              "main_account_number": null,
              "property_account_number": null,
              "branch_account_number": null
            },
            "surface_for_hot_water_consumption": null,
            "metering_service_data": null
          },
          "contacts": []
        }
      ],
      "tenants": [
        {
          "person_id": 904316,
          "person_reference": "2162801",
          "person_first_name": "APREMIS",
          "person_last_name": "APREMIS",
          "birth_date": "1950-01-01",
          "title": "Association",
          "salutation": "ASSO",
          "status": "P",
          "arrival_date": "2019-03-28",
          "departure_date": null,
          "parent_link": null
        }
      ],
      "insurances": [
        {
          "id": 334394,
          "name": "MAIF",
          "insurance_policy": "2388193 H",
          "reference": "",
          "home": "",
          "start_date": "2021-01-01",
          "end_date": "2021-12-31"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const filtered = input.results.filter(result => {
  return result.leases.some(l => l.status === 'P');
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget that JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters. The character `p` is different from `P`. Leases value is `P` not `p` in your JSON data.

**Solution**

```
myActiveContractItems.results.filter((item)=>{
    return item.leases.filter((lease)=>{
        return lease.status ==='P'; // Or LeaseStatus.Primary 
  }).length > 0;
});
```

1. Act on `myActiveContractItems.results` array and filter it
2. Filter `item.leases` by status (in this case equal to `P`)
3. If Filtered Leases has items (`length > 0`), contract can be included in the main filter

**Reusable Solution**

Ideally, you can create a general function to filter by lease status and use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method instead of check the `length` of the elements with that status

```
let filterByLeaseStatus = (leaseStatus)=>
myActiveContractItems.results.filter((item)=>
item.leases.some((lease)=>lease.status ===leaseStatus));
```

and then use it `filterByLeaseStatus('P')` or `filterByLeaseStatus(LeaseStatus.Primary)`

Answer (score 0):

By calling *Array.map*, in the inner function all you are doing is mapping the array elements to an array of boolean values.  As long as there is one lease in the collection then the contract item should get returned by *Array.filter* (since an empty array is falsey).

Instead use *Array.some* in the inner function which will return true if at least one element matches the predicate.

```
myActiveContractItems.filter((item) => 
  item.leases.some((lease) => lease.status === LeaseStatus.Primary));
```